# Add a click event to the label of the node

Tags: javascript, echarts

1:I wrote an HTML file as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/echarts/4.3.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main" style="width: 400px;height: 200px;background-color: bisque;"></div>
    <script>
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("main"));
        var option = {

            series: [{
                type: 'tree',
                data: [{
                    name: "AAA",
                    children: [{
                        name: "BBB"
                    }]
                }],
                label: {
                    position: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    align: 'left',
                    fontSize: 10,
                },
            }]
        };
        myChart.setOption(option);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2:Open with browser
[image]

3:I want to trigger an event when I click on the label in the tree node.What shall I do?

Comment: Can you show how these elements end up rendering in the DOM? If you open Chrome DevTools, click the Elements tab, and press the button in the top left that shows a cursor in a rectangle, you can select the element and it will highlight the corresponding HTML

Comment: Echarts render by default use the Canvas for display data in visual layer. After drawing  stage the canvas can't be represent as DOM-nodes, it's just binary image data. If you want to explore canvas structure you need to call Zrender object `myChart.getZr()`

Answer (score 3):

It's easy. Just start to listen click events like this:

```js
myChart.on('click', 'series.tree', e => console.log(e));
```

where `series.tree` is events filter param. In the response you will get event object:

```js
{
    componentType: "series"
    componentSubType: "tree"
    componentIndex: 0
    seriesType: "tree"
    seriesIndex: 0
    seriesId: "series00"
    seriesName: "series0"
    name: "BBB"
    dataIndex: 2
    data: {name: "BBB"}
    dataType: "main"
    value: undefined
    color: "lightsteelblue"
    dimensionNames: ["value"]
    encode: {value: Array(1)}
    marker: "<span style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;border-radius:10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:lightsteelblue;"></span>"
    $vars: (3) ["seriesName", "name", "value"]
    event: {type: "click", event: MouseEvent, target: t, topTarget: t, cancelBubble: false, …}
    type: "click"
}
```

Also you can listen any click when subscribe to events without filter:

```js
myChart.on('click', e => console.log(e));
```

Useful documents:

- [Echarts API :: Mouse events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events.click)
- [Tutorial :: Events and Actions in ECharts](https://www.echartsjs.com/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts)

Comment: What version of ehcarts do you use?Version 4.3.0 does not work.

Comment: I used last version 4.7 but it must work in 4.3. Probably you're doing something wrong, look at a example: https://jsfiddle.net/1ys87pqu/

Comment: It works on node, not label. Currently there is no way to capture any event from the label.

Comment: Then use events of ZRender.